# Model named "Media" has get/set for "Medium", how to turn off pluralizer

Tags: sequelize.js

Suppose I have a couple models, Media and MediaDerivative.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Media = sequelize.define('Media', {
    // fields
  });

  Media.associate = (models) => {
    Media.hasMany(models.MediaDerivative);
  };
};
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const MediaDerivative = sequelize.define('MediaDerivative', {
    // fields
  });

  MediaDerivative.associate = (models) => {
    MediaDerivative.belongsTo(models.Media);
  };
};
```

Tables are created named `Media` and `MediaDerivatives` as expected.  However, the helper functions on a `MediaDerivative` instance are named as follows:

- `createMedium`
- `getMedium`
- `setMedium`

How can I configure my models such that these are named `createMedia`, `getMedia`, and `setMedia`?

Comment: Will you always use "media" over "medium"? You can configure the model definition so that the singular form is also "media", like `sequelize.define('Media', attributes, { name: { singular: 'Media', plural: 'Media' } })`.

Comment: @approxiblue That's the answer I'm looking for, thanks!  Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequelize uses [node.inflection](https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.inflection) to convert model names between its plural/singular forms.

If you always prefer "media" over "medium", you can [configure the model definition](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#naming-strategy) so that the singular form is also "media":

```js
const Media = sequelize.define('Media', attributes, {
  name: {
    singular: 'Media',
    plural: 'Media',
  }
});
```